# How to see two time series following same distribution easily?

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions, normal-distribution

This is related to Stoeffer's Time Series book Chapter 3, Example 3.6

Let $w_t\sim iid Normal(0,25),v_t\sim idd Normal(0,1)$ where $25,1$ are variances. It is not hard to check the following two time series have the same distribution at any $t$ by normality and MGF.

$x_t=w_t+1/5 w_{t-1}$

$y_t=v_t+5v_{t-1}$

Why $x_t,y_t$ have the same distribution obvious or intuitive? It will take at least 2 lines to check same distribution by MGF though it is easy. However, the book seems finding this fact obvious without arguing the case.

Comment: The intuition comes from noting that the definition of $(y_t)$ is equivalent to reversing the direction of $(x_t)$ -- and obviously a direction reversal does not change the marginal distributions.

Comment: @whuber That does make story clearer. Thanks.